# How to display many to many relationship fields (if the many to many relationship is using 'through') in the Django Admin Area?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I know it is easy to display fields for foreign keys in the admin area, but how do I display fields for many to many relationships if through is used?

Models.py:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, through='PizzaTopping')

class Topping(models.Model):
    topping = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
```

Admin.py:

```
class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('toppings')
        }),
    })
)
```

This produces the following error:

```
<class 'pizzas.admin.PizzaAdmin'>: (admin.E013) The value of 'fieldsets[0][1]["fields"]' cannot include the many-to-many field 'toppings' because that field manually specifies a relationship model.
```

I want to display a box or listbox which allows me to select a topping.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can display the toppings as inlines.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ToppingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PizzaTopping

class Pizza(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ToppingInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('toppings',)
```

See the admin docs on [working with many-to-many models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) for more info.